# Invoking su in emacs' eshell

Tags: emacs, eshell

I can run normal linux commands in eshell as a non-root user. When I try to su to root, all the usual linux commands are gone (ls, cat, etc.) How do I fix this?

Comment: are those commands also 'gone' when you log as root in a normal shell ?

Comment: No they aren't. M-x shell works fine even if I log as root.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use tramp:

```
cd /su::/etc/
ls
```

then eshell will run command "remotly" using su.

After testing, it seem that ls do work, but there is a problem with some (but not all) external command.

Comment: ls does work fine, but I still can't run "yum", fedora's package manager. I get "/usr/bin/python: can't open file '/su:root@localhost:/usr/bin/yum': [Errno 2] No such file or directory" instead. Running the package manager is the primary reason I want to login as root.